# Mono- Using Mono.texteditor widget

Tags: c#, text, mono, text-editor

I'm messing around with Mono, and trying to get a syntax-highlighting text-editor working.

I'm trying to use Mono.TextEditor. I've referenced it, and my project builds, but I always get the following error when running:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has    occurred.
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP
```

I don't know what is causing the problem. It doesn't matter if I try and load the Mono.TexeEditor component with the GUI builder, or if I just create it with code like as follows:

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using Mono.TextEditor; 

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{   
    Mono.TextEditor.TextEditor textEditor = new Mono.TextEditor.TextEditor();
public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build ();
    textEditor.ShowAll();
}

protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{
    Application.Quit ();
    a.RetVal = true;
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm a bit of a n00b when it comes to Mono, so bear with me, and forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Edit: I'm on Linux Mint, if that's relevant.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, I am too having the same problem on a 64 bit box and I am trying to make my own editor.